# Boolean Algebra fundementals

Tags: boolean-algebra

A disjunction A OR B truth table has A , B , and A OR B  but mine has A ,B C, with  A or B or C could some please explain this

Comment: $A + B + C = 1$ if at least one of them is $1$, and $A + B + C = 0$ if they're all $0$. You could group it into $A + (B + C)$ if you want and consider $A, B + C$, and $A + (B + C)$, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

It's really all the same thing.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|cc}
 A & B & A\vee B \\ \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \star\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c|c|c|cc}
 A & B & C & A\vee B\vee C \\ \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \star\end{array}$$

etc. The truth value of $A\vee B\vee C$ is $1$ whenever any of the $A$, $B$ or $C$ is $1$. It is only zero if all of them are zero (in the rows marked $\star$). Replace $1$ with $T$ and $0$ with $F$ to your liking.